# Calling PHP functions through AJAX using jQuery callback parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have problems with AJAX results using jQuery.

I have defined these functions:

```
<script>
    function hello(callback, funct, val) {
        var ret = 0;
        console.log(val);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'SGWEB/header.php',
            data: {
                'funct': funct,
                'val': val
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            // you may safely use results here
            console.log(data);
            callback(data);
        });
    };

    function change() {
        hello(function (ret) {
                  console.log(ret);
                  $("#b1").text(ret);
              }, "hello", 1);
    }; 

    change();
</script>
```

**SGWEB/header.php:**

```
extract($_GET);
$validFunctions = array("readPin","hello");
if(in_array($funct, $validFunctions)) $funct();

// functions
// ....

function hello($val) {
    if ($val == 1) {
        echo "1";
    } else 
        echo "2";
}
```

The problem I have is that the AJAX passes only the first parameter in data `{'funct': funct}` and it's working, but `val` is completely ignored (it always echoes "2").

How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Does the console show anything?

Comment: You pass a **function** to `hello()` which is false when you compare it to `1`.. that's why it always goes to the `else` branch.

Comment: @A1rPun javascript hello function (top of code) expects a callback function as it's first argument... the hello function at the bottom of code is a PHP function (I think)

Comment: I'd like to see more of `SGWEB/header.php` to see how it's handling the incoming query to end up calling the hello function ... surely the code marked PHP function isn't the whole content of that header.php

Comment: You need to fix your original question. The code needs to be properly indented so that we can read it better. It's simple courtesy.

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX. The code looks properly indented now.

Comment: You need to add the proper PHP. I dont see the contents of `SGWEB/header.php` and I dont see how you are obtaining your GET data in PHP.

Comment: @CodeGodie sorry, I forget to add that part! EDIT: code edited

Comment: in `index.php ` you have a JS script calling a `hello()` function, I hope you dont think you can call PHP functions through JS right?

Comment: @CodeGodie No no, that's why I'm using ajax!

Comment: @Ghesio I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to pass the `$val` parameter to your function in PHP

Change this:

```
if (in_array($funct, $validFunctions)) $funct();
```

to this:

```
if (in_array($funct, $validFunctions)) $funct($val);
```

Another problem is that your AJAX is expecting JSON as you are defining it here `dataType:'json'` but you are not sending that. I would redo your ajax call like this so that you can see other errors as well:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'SGWEB/header.php',
    data: {
        'funct': funct,
        'val': val
    },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        callback(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my error was a little dumb. Tried the PHP side of the answer and is working, tomorrow I'll try the JS code!

Comment: awesome, glad i was able to help

Comment: Hi again... do you also know how can I use this type of ajax function in a for loop? can provide code if needed. Thanks

Comment: Yea, but if you can provide code, it would be best so that I can see what you mean.

Comment: I see, are you getting any errors on your console? Also, I would post a new question with this information. Would you be able to do that?

Comment: Moved to new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626582/jquery-ajax-call-not-executed-in-for-loop)

Comment: I will check it out now