# Jquery Ajax call not executed in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop

Using this function

```
  function readPinMode(callback,pin){
     $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: path,
        data: {
        'funct': "readPinMode", //function included and working ou of loops
        'pin': pin,
        'php': 0
     },
     success: function (result) {
        //console.log(result);
        callback(result);
     },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
    }
   });
 };
```

in this way, simply does not do nothing:

```
      $( document ).ready(function() {
  <?php
  $js_array = json_encode($GLOBALS['gpio']); // got from included file, working
  echo "var pins = ". $js_array . ";\n";
  ?>
  console.log( "Document ready." );
  for (i = 0; i < pins.length; i++) {
        var mode = "m" + pins[i];
        function initMode(){
        readPinMode(function(ret){
        console.log(ret);
        $(mode).text(ret);
        console.log(mode);
      }, pins[i]);
    };
  }
```

It enters the for loop (I can log in console `mode` and `pins[i]`, they are working) but the function seems to not be called.
Console does not show anything.

Is there a way to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Never ajax in a loop.

Comment: `ret` is the result of the ajax success methos

Comment: what is `function initMode()` doing there ?? you are just defining a function. and not executing it.. as it has the logic to call AJAX and receive the results

Comment: First of all, add var before i. And you don't need that function initMode() {}, it just declares function inside of loop and nothing happens.

Comment: what is `mode` suppose to be? is it an HTML element ID? and what are `pins` exactly?

Comment: @CodeGodie `mode` is HTML element ID, yes. [it must be `$("#" + mode)`, found out now this error]. `pins` is a numerical array.

Comment: @Ghesio Got it. Thanks. I provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using callback functions, however you did miss a couple of things. You are forgetting to call your `initMode` function and `mode` should be an ID like you mentioned:

```
<script>
    function readPinMode(callback, pin) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'SGWEB/header.php',
            data: {
                'funct': "readPinMode", //function included and working ou of loops
                'pin': pin,
                'php': 0
            },
            success: function (result) {
                callback(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }

    function initMode(mode, pin) {
        readPinMode(function (ret) {
            $(mode).text(ret);
        }, pin);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var pins = <?= json_encode($GLOBALS['gpio']) ?>;
        for (i = 0; i < pins.length; i++) {
            var mode = "#m" + pins[i];
            initMode(mode, pins[i]);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here's a [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/5h805vq5/) I created so that you can see how it works.

Comment: Now it has a proper closure. +1

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to not use a real loop which needs a proper closure, but instead run again in the success

```
<?php
  $js_array = json_encode($GLOBALS['gpio']); // got from included file,  working
  echo "var pins = ". $js_array . ";\n";
?>
var cnt = 0;
function readPinMode(){
  if (cnt>=pins.length) return;      
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: path,
    data: {
    'funct': "readPinMode", //function included and working ou of loops
    'pin': pins[cnt],
    'php': 0
   },
   success: function (result) {
      //console.log(result);
      $("#mode").append(result)
      cnt++;
      readPinMode();
   },
   error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(error);
   }
 });
}
$(function() { readPinMode(); });
```

Proof of concept:

```js
var pins = ["pin1", "pin2", "pin3"];
var cnt = 0;

function readPinMode() {
  if (cnt >= pins.length) return;

  document.write('<br/>pin:' + pins[cnt]); // your Ajax

  cnt++;
  readPinMode();
}
$(function() {
  readPinMode();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Show me how much you like it ;)

Comment: Nice approach, but this works only for first element!

Comment: I like it so much that did +1 :)

Comment: @Ghesio - I need more detail as to how it only worked for the first element. Did the script stop? was there console messages? how does the rendering of the pins array look? Please see the proof of concepts. I had a typo in the pin/pins

Comment: @mplungjan The script got executed, the array is fine. It logs only the first element of array (`console.log(result);` from ajax) and no other errors in console.

Comment: As you can see in my proof of concept, the loop works if the array and server response works

Answer (score 0):

I think its syntax error, Try this code

```
console.log( "Document ready." );
  for (i = 0; i < pins.length; i++) {
        var mode = "m" + pins[i];       
        readPinMode(function(ret){
        console.log(ret);
        $(mode).text(ret);
        console.log(mode);
      }, pins[i]);       
  }
```

I removed the `function initMode()` as it creates same function definition over and over again which overrides the exiting function, and its all messy. You should not define a function inisde a loop as the final function will be of the last loop. Also there is no need for you to define the function inside a loop in this scenario.

Here is a [Working Prototype Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/u4fvw7Lg/)

Comment: Tried this code, it only works for last iteration of for

Comment: what do you get in console??

Comment: I get only the last `console.log(result);` from for loop

Comment: @Ghesio The code is working 100% as expected.. it is looping correctly and the console has the output for all the loops.. check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/u4fvw7Lg/